# Communicate With React Js from Android Webview

Tags: android, reactjs

How to send data from android webview to React Js? I know to send data from React js to Android is pretty straight forward. However, I need to read data in React Js that I am passing via webview. For example, I sent an event say: `webview.loadUrl("javascript:sayHello('Hello From Android')")`
and in React js I want to be able to get that data from sayHello function. I tried this inside the jsx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        {`
          ${function sayHello(data) {
            alert(data);
          }}
        `}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually solved this issue while ago. Due to lack of time didn't get chance to post the answer. It was actually pretty simple. All I had to do is add an eventListener and dispatch that event from index.html under public folder. Then listen to that same event from whatever class I needed to. Here's an example:

```
<script>
  function mobileGoBack() {
    window.addEventListener("onNativeGoBack", () => {});
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("onNativeGoBack"));
  }
</script>
```

Then Listen to that same event in some class

```
const Example = () => {
 // you can use useEffect or not up to you!
 useEffect(() => {
   window.addEventListener("onNativeGoBack", () => {
     // Do your stuff
 });
   return () => {
     window.removeEventListener("onNativeGoBack", () => {});
   };
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. is there any idea to pass a value/param to 'onNativeGoBack'?

Comment: I found that I can pass param by modifing the CustomEvent, like: window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("onNativeGoBack", { detail: { param-to-pass } }));